# How to retrieve first line in a row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've following table in MySQL,

```
MyData
------ //header data separator
test
test_2
--- //row separator
test
t
iuey
--- //row separator
yi
t
```

I want to retrieve first line, that is **test, test, yi** using SQL query. Basically I want to split each row by `\n`, without using stored proc or any user defined functions. I tried following, but it didn't worked.

```
select substr(MyData, 0, length('test ')) from MyTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(MyData, '\n', 1) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Awesome! It works. I wasn't aware of `SUBSTRING_INDEX` method. I'll mark it as answer in few minutes. Currently SO isn't allowing me to do so.